# Debian - new PHP5 installed, but apache shows old version

Tags: debian, php-5.5

I download/configure/make/install a new version of php5 on my debian with success. When I run php -v at console it shows the new version installed. But phpinfo on webserver shows the old version of php! I already restart apache. Did I skip any step?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Although the question is not really a programming question, I'll give you a hint anyway: using the standard `./configure ; make ; make install` is not the recommended way to install on Debian.  Use normal packages if you can (in your case, `apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5`).  If you compiled yourself in order to get a version that has not yet been packaged, look at the possibility of modifying the source package for `php5` to incorporate the changes you want.

Comment: Yes, I need --enable-maintainer-zts  option enabled. I tried to modify the  php5  package, but I got errors during compilation. I will try another stuffs. thks.